# asp LinkButton to call a C# method

Tags: asp.net

According to MSDN I can have an OnClick for a LinkButton --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclick(v=VS.90).aspx

However, When I try to do following

```
 foeach(var item in items)
 {
 var link = new LinkButton
           {
               Text = item.Policy.PolNumber,
               OnClick = 
           };
 }
```

I don't have access to OnClick :-( where I can specify a C# function to be called. I do however have OnClientClick but that is for calling javascript function :-( Right?
I also tried

```
var link = new LinkButton {Text = item.Policy.PolNumber};
link.Click +=new EventHandler(link_Click);

protected void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do my stuff
}
```

This is never being executed :-(

I am trying to achieve this with a ASP table. In the foreach loop I am also doing.

```
var tRow = new TableRow();
var link = new LinkButton {Text = holding.Policy.PolNumber};
link.Click +=new EventHandler(link_Click);
var tCell = new TableCell ();
tCell.Controls.Add(link);
tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
```

Comment: Can you provide some more details please as to when/where are you creating this link button and binding the link_Click to Click?

Comment: I am creating linkbutton on click of another Button. All binding I am doing is the one I have pasted; is there more that needs to be done? All I wanna do is call a c# function when someone clicks a linkButton.

Comment: Your question greatly depends on where in the lifecycle these buttons are being created. Are they in a GridView (which is what I suspect)? Then RowDataBound would be ideal to add this code, although you'd be better off having it as template column, but I digress..

Comment: No this is not a GridView. This is in a ASP table. Let me edit my question with more info. thanks

Comment: Have you tried link.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

Comment: Yeah, I just did that, that didn't help either :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the link button to controls container or some other container on your page. That should be having the property  runat="server". Looks like your linkbutton is not having the property  runat="server" set. You can check in one of the replies in the following [link](http://forums.asp.net/p/832974/832974.aspx) for a sample dynamic link button creation.